# App Promo Site - iPhone app website template in landscape

Tags: iphone, templates, web, landscape

Does anyone know where I can find a template for an iphone app website where an iphone is used as the frame for videos AND is in landscape? I've had serious trouble finding one. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ThemeForest.com](http://themeforest.net/searches?term=iPhone&type=files) has quite a few templates for `iPhone` sites. They are very inexpensive too.

Here are a few specific templates as well:

From [Templatis](http://www.templatis.com/00082-iphone-app-template.php),

[One with iPad](http://www.templatis.com/00153-ipad-app-etchasketch-template.php)

[This one](http://www.templatis.com/00090-iphone-map-app-template.php) actually has landscape & portrait

[A Tennis Theme](http://www.templatis.com/00168-tennis-iphone-app-web-template.php)

[A Golf Theme](http://www.templatis.com/00166-golf-iphone-app-web-template.php)

Here are [some more](http://www.templatis.com/iphone-app-web-templates.php)

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for something like Templatis. I knew about theme forest however I also neglected to check there. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Templatis seems to be out of business.  Or at least they were having some trouble with their website when I tried to buy their template.

Funny that landscape templates are still not so easy to find. I ended up going with Appland via Theme Forest: 
http://themeforest.net/item/appland-responsive-bootstrap-parallax-app-landing-page/3109123

(I have no biz affiliation with this outfit, other than buying this theme.)